# Unscented Kalman Filtering?

Tags: ros, filter, kalman

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use an unscented kalman filter (UKF) in ROS to do state estimation. I can't find any ROS packages that implement an UKF so I've been looking around at filtering libraries for C++ that I could use within ROS. Does anyone have any recommendations? I've found the following libraries but many are poorly documented or inactive. Any suggestions?

**UKF support:**

[Bayes++](http://bayesclasses.sourceforge.net/Bayes++.html)

[bfilt](http://code.google.com/p/bfilt/)

**No UKF support:**

[Mobile Robot Programming Toolkit](http://www.mrpt.org/Kalman_Filters) (The main page lists UKFs but the code doesn't appear to implement them)

[Orocos Bayesian Filtering Library](http://www.orocos.org/bfl)

[KFilter](http://kalman.sourceforge.net/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12424/unscented-kalman-filtering?/) by [Andrew Chambers](https://answers.ros.org/users/435/andrew-chambers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-12-21

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2011-12-21**:
Hi Andrew! OpenCV implements Kalman Filter,  Extended Kalman Filter (EKF) and is fully integrated with ROS. But I am afraid it doesn't implement UKF (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you already know you want to do an [unscented KF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Unscented_Kalman_filter), I assume you understand the mathematics. I would suggest just implementing the math yourself using the matrix/vector capabilities of either OpenCV or Eigen libraries which are already part of ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2011-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4